# Vagrant unable to locate Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

On `Ubuntu 16.04.01`

Using `vagrant 1.8.1` and `virtualbox 5.1.12`.
I have already set

```
VBOX_INSTALL_PATH=/usr/bin/virtualbox
VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH=/usr/bin/virtualbox
```

Getting the following error:

```
$ vagrant up
No usable default provider could be found for your system.

Vagrant relies on interactions with 3rd party systems, known as
"providers", to provide Vagrant with resources to run development
environments. Examples are VirtualBox, VMware, Hyper-V.

The easiest solution to this message is to install VirtualBox, which
is available for free on all major platforms.

If you believe you already have a provider available, make sure it
is properly installed and configured. You can see more details about
why a particular provider isn't working by forcing usage with
`vagrant up --provider=PROVIDER`, which should give you a more specific
error message for that particular provider.
```

as also this one:

```
$ vagrant up --provider=VIRTUALBOX
The provider 'VIRTUALBOX' could not be found, but was requested to
back the machine 'default'. Please use a provider that exists.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: To save your typing, you can copy from here:
https://github.com/romans1212notes/vagrant-virtualbox-fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a [compatibility issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7588#issuecomment-233035591) with the particular versions of vagrant and virtualbox.

A workaround seems to be the following:

**A.**

`cd /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver`

edit `meta.rb` and add

`"5.1" => Version_5_1`

under the line: `"5.0" => Version_5_0,` (should be around line 63)

**B.**

`cd /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/providers/virtualbox/`

edit `plugin.rb` and add

`autoload :Version_5_1, File.expand_path("../driver/version_5_1", __FILE__)`

under the line: `autoload :Version_5_0, File.expand_path("../driver/version_5_0", __FILE__)` (should be around line 58)

**C.**

`cd /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver`

create a file named `version_5_1.rb` with [these contents](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mitchellh/vagrant/b57b0e0d48fe8b4196ca6b7e01bb6c1ecb4b69f9/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/version_5_1.rb).

Hopefully this tackles the problem.